# Jquery - How to split and get the actual data from an XML file.?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, xml-parsing

Want to split and get the actual data from an XML, where multiple records exists.

XML

```
<description>
    <div><b>Article_Title:</b> Title_Content</div>
    <div><b>Article_Summary:</b> Summary_Content</div>
    <div><b>Article_Date:</b> 05/08/2013</div>
</description>
```

From the above code i want only "Title_Content", "Summary_Content"  and "05/08/2013" to be retrieved.

What is the best and optimal way to get these content.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

look at this function [jQuery.parseXML](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/)

Comment: This will only create a valid XML document. Which op already has.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it was parsed as valid XML

```
var values = [];

$('description div').clone().find('b').remove().end().each(function(ix){
   values[ix] = $(this).text();   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following

HTML

```
<description>
    <div><b>Article_Title:</b> Title_Content</div>
    <div><b>Article_Summary:</b> Summary_Content</div>
    <div><b>Article_Date:</b> 05/08/2013</div>
</description>
```

Javascript

```
var descriptions = document.getElementsByTagName("description"),
    results = [];

Array.prototype.forEach.call(descriptions, function (description) {
    var result = {};

    result.title = description.children[0].lastChild.textContent;
    result.summary = description.children[1].lastChild.textContent;
    result.date = description.children[2].lastChild.textContent;

    results.push(result);
});

console.log(results);
```

Output

```
date: " 05/08/2013"
summary: " Summary_Content"
title: " Title_Content"
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/NDeEr/)

If you don't want the leading space or trailing space then add `.trim()` to the end of each `textContent`

The `forEach` loop is only necessary if you have more than one such block defined.